# How to get overflow only on x and not y

Tags: html, alignment, overflow

What I want is the following: a gallery with thumbails on the bottom, in a div, with a big main content above it in the middle.

I want the thumbnails on the bottom to scroll only with x. I have done the overflow-x: scroll and overflow-y:hidden.

But the first 8 thumbnails are nicely aligned from left to right ( x ) and the others are being put UNDERNEATH the first 8. Where I want them ALL to be from left t- right only, so ONLY on the x.

How do I do that in the div with css?

Comment: Give a [mcve] in the question.

Comment: give some expample code or image capture

Comment: Perhaps you can place your thumbnails with inline-block and white-space:nowrap; to force all thumbnails on the same line, but not sure that's what you want. Please show your code :)

Comment: Pepi, your great! That's exactly what I want! Sorry to the other guys for not showing code, I figured this was eassier to explain then just showing code.. Thanks Pepi for your help!

Comment: You're welcome ! Don't hesitate to mark the question as resolved :)

Answer (score 2):

You can force your thumbnails to stay on the same line like this :

```
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
```